MARGIN Y PADDING DE COL Y
tengo un problema, quiero que las imagenes del carrusel estén mas juntas porque no se ven las flechas del previus y next, no puedo entender como modificar el padding o el margin de estas. Como puedo hacer para que esten un poco mas pegadas? Pongo solo el primer ejemplo
<div class="content">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-theme="dark " class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-indicators">
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0"
                    class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
                    aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
                    aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col">
                            <img class="fotos" src="//d2r9epyceweg5n.cloudfront.net/stores/001/531/943/rte/1553179191100 (1).jfif" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."></div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <img class="fotos" src="//d2r9epyceweg5n.cloudfront.net/stores/001/531/943/rte/acindar.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."></div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <img class="fotos"src="//d2r9epyceweg5n.cloudfront.net/stores/001/531/943/rte/Sin título11.png"class="d-block w-100" alt="..."></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



Si no compartes los estilos aplicados, es difícil ayudarte. Te recomiendo completar el [tour] y entender lo que es un [mcve]
